# Opening multiple Iframe in IE using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a page, where you can download files from a list. What I do to download the file, is insert an `Iframe` into the page, then set the source of the frame to point to the URL of the content which is to be downloaded, which of course has a content disposition depending on the file type to be downloaded, which will force the `Iframe` to prompt the download file dialog box.

Doing this works fine in all browsers. The problem is when inserting multiple `Iframe`. This is brought by the case, that the user is allowed to select a couple of files to download, then download them.

What I do to do this is insert multiple `Iframe`, which all have a unique source corresponding to the URL of the file they want to download. It works fine in all browsers, except in IE. What happens in IE, is that in most cases, for example, when i select 4 files to download, and I insert 4 `Iframe`, only 3 downloads are prompted.

What may be causing this? What could be a solution to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Don't older versions of IE have a limit on simultaneous file downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's Internet Explorer typically limits you to download between 2 and 4 files simultaneously, not any more. This can be quite annoying:

**Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions** limit the number of files that you can download at one time to two.

**Internet Explorer 8** limits the number of files that you can download at one time to six.

**Internet Explorer 9** [increases the connections-per-proxy limit to 12](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/02/10/fiddler-is-better-with-internet-explorer-9.aspx).

This is an issue on the browser it self, and can be dealt-with by the user changing the configuration:

**See** [How do I configure Internet Explorer to download more than two files at one time?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402)

---

**Additionally**, a `.reg` file can be used to set other limitations:

1. Save this inside a file named `change_ie_file_download_limit.reg`.

   ```
   REGEDIT4 

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings] 
   "MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server"=dword:00000010 
   "MaxConnectionsPerServer"=dword:00000008
   ```
2. Right click on the .reg file and click on Merge.
3. Click on *Run*, *Yes*, *Yes*, and *OK* when prompted.

**Note:** this is applied to Windows 7, earlier versions may have different steps, but the basis is the same.